# Data is not place in datatable, data is coming from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have ajax json data from ajax call and response is json_encode.

```
$user=array('id'=>$val->id,'username'=>$name,'contactno'=>$val->contact_no);
echo json_encode($user);
```

I am accessing this and placing in the datatable .
I have script code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>list/people',
    success: function(response) {   
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "data": response, // <-- your array of objects
            "columns": [
                {"data": "id"}, 
                {"data": "username"},
                {"data": "contactno"}
             ]
        });
    }, 
    });
});
```

I am unable to get the json data in datatable. Please help

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No error showing in console

Comment: If you don't get JS error in browser console when sending data theh the problem is in PHP code. Please add PHP script that is located at [base_url]/list/people] and should write data to database. Without it it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: $content_array = $this->list_model->users_list();
//print_r($content_array); die;
foreach($content_array as $key=>$val)
{
$id = $val->id;
$name = $val->user_name; 
$contact=>$val->contact_no;      
     $user=array('id'=>$val->id,'username'=>$name,'contactno'=>$val->contact_no);  
}   
echo json_encode(array("data"=>$user));

Comment: My model:   public function users_list(){
$this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from('table');     
  $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
         $query = $this->db->get();   
 return $query->result();
  }

Answer (score 0):

Use the datatable ajax syntax

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>list/people",
    "type": "POST"
  }
});
```

php:

```
$user =[];
$content_array = $this->list_model->users_list(); 

foreach($content_array as $key=>$val) { 
 $id = $val->id;
 $name = $val->user_name;
 $contact=>$val->contact_no;
 $user[]=array('id'=>$val->id,'username'=>$name,'contactno'=>$v‌​al->contact_no);
}   
echo json_encode(array("data"=>$user));
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot with your xhr request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajax DataTable for this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax":{
          url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>list/people'
          type: "post",  // method  , by default get,
          data : function ( d ) {
                //any data that you want to send with request
                /*
                  var dt_params = {'myKey' : 'MyValue'};
                  $.extend(d, dt_params);
                */
             },
          complete : function(response){
              // you will receive data here
          }
      }
    });
  });
```

and data from server would be same as

$user=array('id'=>$val->id,'username'=>$name,'contactno'=>$val->contact_no);
echo json_encode($user);exit;

Answer (score 0):

your array must be in this format

```
$user = array(
    array('id'=>$val->id,'username'=>$name,'contactno'=>$val->contact_no)
);
```

since you are using datatable.

Datatable attribute 'data' must be format like this in javascript

```
[{
    'id': 1,
    'username': 'my username',
    'contact_no': 'my contact no.'
}]
```